# Static const in Kotlin from Java class name

Tags: java, constants, kotlin

I usually have this in Java:

```
package some.package;
public class Clz {
    public static final String ACTION_DIVE = Clz.class.getName() + ".action.DIVE";
}
```

that is accessible from outside that class as `Clz.ACTION_DIVE` and the value will be `"some.package.Clz.action.DIVE"`.

How can I do the same in Kotlin class `Clz` so that it can be accessed in the same way from outside Java classes? I tried the following but it does not compile because it is not a constant:

```
package some.package
object Clz {
    const val ACTION_DIVE = Clz.javaClass.name + ".action.DIVE"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`Clz::class.java.name`

See [Class references](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#class-references) in the official Kotlin documentation.

Comment: Does not work. `const val ACTION_DIVE = Clz::class.java.name + ".action.DIVE"` The error is: `Const val initializer should be a constant value`

Comment: Use `@JvmField` instead of `const` (`const` is only for compile-time constants): https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#static-fields

Comment: I guess that's it. @JvmField. Thanks!

Comment: The question asks for a static const from a class name, and following the first comment, this doesn't address it-

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
object Clz {
    val ACTION_DIVE = Clz::class.java.name + ".action.DIVE"
}
```

Notice that since it's calling [`java`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/java.html) extension property the `ACTION_DIVE` may not be `const`.

If you really needed a const <s>you can do</s> **you could, in older versions of Kotlin compiler, do**:

```
object Clz {
    const val ACTION_DIVE = "" + Clz::class + ".action.DIVE"
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with const : `const val ACTION_DIVE = "" + Clz::class + ".action.DIVE"`

Comment: @StephaneL I guess it used to work in older version of Kotlin compiler. It was probably a bug though.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a `companion object` inside your class and put the constant property inside.

```
class Clz {

    companion object{
         var ACTION_DIVE = Clz::class.simpleName + ".action.DIVE"
    }
}
```

Then you can access the property

```
println(Clz.ACTION_DIVE)
```

Comment: A global mutable variables are rarely a good idea. Nor was it the intention of the author.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to concatenate strings:

```
package some.package

object Clz {
    val ACTION_DIVE = "${Clz::class.java.name}.action.DIVE"
}
```

Comment: This will not compile: "Const 'val' initializer should be a constant value"

Comment: @miensol you are right, I just removed the `const` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

work for me:

```
class FetchWeatherTask : AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>() {
    companion object {
        @JvmField val TAG: String = FetchWeatherTask().javaClass.simpleName
    }
}
```